# PHP GD palette colors

Tags: php, image, colors, gd, palette

In **PHP GD** how can you convert a **truecolor** image to a **palette** without losing ***any*** colors.  With [`imagetruecolortopallete`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagetruecolortopalette.php) it **doesn't work**.  I have a function that runs through all the colors and filters them (eg. grayscale). and It **doesn't retain all colors**, such as this picture of a Lamborghini-

**Picture**

[image]

This is **my code**

```
$im = imagecreatefrompng("lamborghini.png");
$degrees = 0;

$img = imagecreatetruecolor(imagesx($im), imagesy($im));
imagecopy($img, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($im), imagesy($im));
imagetruecolortopalette($img, true, 256);
$t = imagecolorstotal($img);
for ($i = 0; $i < $t; $i++) {
  $rgb = imagecolorsforindex($img, $i);
  $hsv =rgbtohsv($rgb['red'], $rgb['green'], $rgb['blue']);
  $h = $degrees;
  $s = $hsv['s'];
  $v = $hsv['v'];
  while ($h > 360) {$h -= 360;};
        $nrgb = hsvtorgb($h, $s, $v);
  imagecolorset($img, $i, $nrgb['r'], $nrgb['g'], $nrgb['b']);
}
imagecopy($im, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($img), imagesy($img));

header('Content-type: image/png');

imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

And it **looks like this**

[image]

You can see ***it loses colors***. Is there ***any solution***?

Also I don't think it has to do with my code but how [`imagetruecolortopalette`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagetruecolortopalette.php) outputs it

Comment: GD library's palette conversion is fast, but very inaccurate. If you want to use palette, I recommend using commandline [pngquant](https://github.com/pornel/improved-pngquant) via [popen()](http://php.net/popen) — while this will loose *some* colors, the loss won't be as bad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the return on `imagecolorstotal`, you are always getting 256 colors as the return no matter how high you set the number of colors to be dithered to. PNG-8 & GIF formats only support palettes of up to 256 colors. So even if you can use more than 256 in a palette, you'd have to save it back as true color for anyone to be able to use it, thus making the whole conversion process a waste of time. In other words `imagetruecolortopallete` has an upper limit of 256 colors, you cannot go higher.

Here's how you can do it in truecolor, though it's resource intensive. Maybe look into imagemagick if you want to do this more efficiently.

```
$im = imagecreatefrompng("lamb.png");
$img = imagecreatetruecolor(imagesx($im), imagesy($im));
$degrees = 0;
if ($degrees > 360) {$degrees = $degrees % 360 ;}

foreach (range(0, imagesx($im) - 1) as $x ) {
    foreach (range(0, imagesy($im) - 1) as $y) {
        $rgb = imagecolorat($im, $x, $y);
        $r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
        $g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
        $b = $rgb & 0xFF;
        $hsv = rgbtohsv($r,$g,$b);
        $rgb = hsvtorgb($degrees, $hsv['s'], $hsv['v']);
        imagesetpixel($img, $x,$y,imagecolorallocate($img, $rgb['r'], $rgb['g'], $rgb['b']));
    }
}

imagepng($img, 'lamb2.png');
```

Edit: Adding rgbtohsv & hsvtorgb functions. I did not write these functions.

```
function rgbtohsv ($R, $G, $B) {
 // HSV Results:Number 0-1
$HSL = array();

$var_R = ($R / 255);
$var_G = ($G / 255);
$var_B = ($B / 255);

$var_Min = min($var_R, $var_G, $var_B);
$var_Max = max($var_R, $var_G, $var_B);
$del_Max = $var_Max - $var_Min;

$V = $var_Max;

if ($del_Max == 0)
{
$H = 0;
$S = 0;
}
else
{
$S = $del_Max / $var_Max;

$del_R = ( ( ( $var_Max  - $var_R ) / 6 ) + ( $del_Max / 2 ) ) / $del_Max;
$del_G = ( ( ( $var_Max  - $var_G ) / 6 ) + ( $del_Max / 2 ) ) / $del_Max;
$del_B = ( ( ( $var_Max  - $var_B ) / 6 ) + ( $del_Max / 2 ) ) / $del_Max;

if ($var_R == $var_Max) $H = $del_B - $del_G;
else if ($var_G == $var_Max) $H = ( 1 / 3 ) + $del_R - $del_B;
else if ($var_B == $var_Max) $H = ( 2 / 3 ) + $del_G - $del_R;

if ($H<0) $H++;
if ($H>1) $H--;
}

$HSL['h'] = $H;
$HSL['s'] = $S;
$HSL['v'] = $V;

return $HSL;
}

function hsvtorgb ($H, $S, $V) 
{
$RGB = array();

if($S == 0)
{
$R = $G = $B = $V * 255;
}
else
{
$var_H = $H * 6;
$var_i = floor( $var_H );
$var_1 = $V * ( 1 - $S );
$var_2 = $V * ( 1 - $S * ( $var_H - $var_i ) );
$var_3 = $V * ( 1 - $S * (1 - ( $var_H - $var_i ) ) );

if ($var_i == 0) { $var_R = $V ; $var_G = $var_3 ; $var_B = $var_1 ; }
else if ($var_i == 1) { $var_R = $var_2 ; $var_G = $V ; $var_B = $var_1 ; }
else if ($var_i == 2) { $var_R = $var_1 ; $var_G = $V ; $var_B = $var_3 ; }
else if ($var_i == 3) { $var_R = $var_1 ; $var_G = $var_2 ; $var_B = $V ; }
else if ($var_i == 4) { $var_R = $var_3 ; $var_G = $var_1 ; $var_B = $V ; }
else { $var_R = $V ; $var_G = $var_1 ; $var_B = $var_2 ; }

$R = $var_R * 255;
$G = $var_G * 255;
$B = $var_B * 255;
}

$RGB['r'] = $R;
$RGB['g'] = $G;
$RGB['b'] = $B;

return $RGB;
}
```

Comment: what is `rgbtohsv` and `hsvtorgb`

Comment: @EscoMaji I have added those functions to the post.

Answer (score 2):

converting truecolor to palette is always going to involve losing colors, unless your pallette table is big enough to hold every unique color in the image. The lamborghini may very well have more than (say) 255 shades of yellow alone, and then you still need palette slots for the rest of the image on top of that. That's why there's truecolor images. There's no palette, but each pixel can have its own dedicated RGB triplet to more accurately represent the original scene.

That being said, I can't see how converting a truecolor picture will change yellow to red as in your sample images. How exactly are you doing this palette conversion? Sampling each pixel and doing some sort of transformation on it?

Comment: WHat happens if you eliminate the rgb->hsv->rgb roundtrip? See what the imagetruecolortopalette produces? I'm guessing youv'e got an error in the rgbtohsv and/or hsvtorgb function, as even a 'bad' palette generator wouldn't produce that many reds from a source image that essentially has none.

Comment: No I resolved the problem by optionally using palette (for speed) and truecolor for quality.

Answer (score 0):

How about this function: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagetruecolortopalette.php. It might take some messing with the number of colors to get it right, though.

Comment: Do you have `dither` enabled? And how many colors did you specify?

Comment: This is what I have `imagetruecolortopalette($img, true, 256);` so yes

Comment: Try increasing the number of colors from `256` to, say, `512`. If there is any improvement, keep increasing the amount of colors until the quality is acceptable.